# What is the angle between two $b$-quarks when a Higgs boson decays to a $b$-quark pair, in the rest frame of Higgs boson?

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, collision, quantum-chromodynamics, large-hadron-collider

I am generating events of $ep -> Xjv$, ($j$ is a jet, and $v$ shows a neutrino) where $X$ particle decays to a $b$-quark pair. I am going to calculate the angle between two b-quarks in the rest frame of the Higgs particle if the X particle is a Higgs boson. In this situation, b and anti-b are back-to-back and the angle would be 180 degrees. But if the b-pair comes from other particles, like Z bozon, this angle will be different in the Higgs rest frame. I do not know how to calculate this angle in the Higgs rest frame.

Comment: They will always be back-to-back, no matter what particle X is since you will be boosting to the $b \bar{b}$ rest frame.

Comment: This needs monte carlo generation  of the interactions, and the Z decays will be part of it , The Higgs rest frame and the Z rest frame are two different frames and you need the details per event of the event generation in order to have the the correct lorentz tranformation for the bb_bar of the Z to the rest frame of the Higgs.

Comment: Thanks for your answers,
I have generated events using Madgraph, Pythia and Delphes to make ROOT files. Then I have details of all events including vectors of momentum of b-quarks etc. But I have problems calculating, e.g. boosting these vectors to the Higgs rest frame. @annav